# Regex VBA in Access - finding text between two strings

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having a heck of a time with a RegEx question in Access VBA.

My goal is to extract the server from a linked database connection string. Basically, the connection string looks like

> ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=compName\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=databaseName

I am able to get the first regex to work, but it is returning

> SERVER=compName\sqlexpress

I would like this to only return

> compName\sqlexpress

My understanding is the `?<=` operator should allow the RegEx to work correctly, but I get the following error "Method 'Execute' of object 'IRegExp2' failed."

The only documentation I can find for any Microsoft RegEx syntax is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is not the runtime 5.5 VBScript library, but I'm not sure where else to get supported syntax.

Here is the code I'm using to test this. My database has a lot of linked tables.

```
Sub printServerStringInformation()
    Dim rxPattern As String

    rxPattern = "(?=SERVER)(.*)(?=;Trusted)"
    Debug.Print RxMatch(CurrentDb.tableDefs(1).Connect, rxPattern, False)

    rxPattern = "(?<=SERVER)(.*)(?=;Trusted)"
    Debug.Print RxMatch(CurrentDb.tableDefs(1).Connect, rxPattern, False)

End Sub
```

Here is the function I am using:

```
Public Function RxMatch( _
    ByVal SourceString As String, _
    ByVal Pattern As String, _
    Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True) As Variant
 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

    'http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#more
    'http://bytecomb.com/regular-expressions-in-vba/

    'http://xkcd.com/1171/
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    With New RegExp
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
        Set oMatches = .Execute(SourceString)
        If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
            RxMatch = oMatches(0).value
        Else
            RxMatch = ""
        End If
    End With

errHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure why you can't use `?<=`, but if you use regex's selective bracket you should be able to get the info with `"SERVER=(.*?);Trusted"`, then using the string stored in the first regex variable. (something like `oMatches(0).subMatches(0)` ?)

Answer (score 3):

Here goes solution with RegEx (complete code which could be converted into function):

```
Sub qTest_3()

    Dim objRE As New RegExp
    Dim Tekst As String
    Dim Wynik As Variant


    Tekst = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=compName\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=databaseName"
    With objRE
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(^.*;SERVER=)(.*)(;Trusted.*)" 

        Wynik = .Replace(Tekst, "$2")   'only 2nd part of the pattern will be returned

    End With
    Debug.Print Wynik

End Sub
```

Your function changed could be as follows (I added additional parameter setting part of the pattern which should be returned):

```
Public Function RxMatchReturn( _
    ByVal SourceString As String, _
    ByVal Pattern As String, _
    StringPart As Byte, _
    Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True) As Variant
    'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    With New RegExp
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = Pattern
        RxMatchReturn = .Replace(SourceString, "$" & StringPart)
    End With

errHandler:
    Debug.Print err.Description

End Function
```