# How do you use RegEx to return a parsed value?

Tags: regex, ms-access, expression

I have a data column that has a heading value with multiple levels, where I only want the first three levels, but I cannot figure out how to get the parsed value?

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393087/expressing-basic-access-query-criteria-as-regular-expressions) and it shows how to use create a function to return a boolean for the condition, but how would I create a function that would return a parsed value?

This is the Regular Expression that I think I need.

```
^(\d.\d.\d)
```

I'm looking for something that would change `1.2.3.4.5.` to `1.2.3` and similar for any other header I have that has more than three levels.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to put it into my Query Design as a `Field Expression`, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed your input values could have more than one digit between the dots.  In other words, I think you want this ...

```vb
? RegExpGetMatch("1.2.3.4.5.", "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*", 1)
1.2.3
? RegExpGetMatch("1.27.3.4.5.", "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*", 1)
1.27.3
```

If that is the correct behavior, here is the function I used.

```vb
Public Function RegExpGetMatch(ByVal pSource As String, _
    ByVal pPattern As String, _
    ByVal pGroup As Long) As String

    'requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
    'Dim re As RegExp
    'Set re = New RegExp
    'late binding; no reference needed
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = pPattern
    RegExpGetMatch = re.Replace(pSource, "$" & pGroup)
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21264857/77335) by [KazJaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2143262/kazjaw).  His answer taught me how to select the match group with `RegExp.Replace`.

In a query run within an Access session, you could use the function like this:

```sql
SELECT
    RegExpGetMatch([Data Column], "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*", 1) AS parsed_value
FROM YourTable;
```

Note however a custom VBA function is not usable for queries run from outside an Access session.

Comment: I like this idea, but what about if I have `1` or `1.2`? I don't want it to be converted to `1.0.0` or `1.2.0` respectively.

Comment: It does not convert `1` to `1.0.0` or `1.2` to `1.2.0`.  Try it when you can.

Comment: Awesome, got it working, I was using the wrong `Data Column`, gave me the wrong value. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your RegEx to `^(\d\.\d\.\d)`. You need to escape the `.` since it has a special meaning in RegExp.