# Extractng Variable Names from VBA Scripts

Tags: vba

I want to Get List of Variables used in the Script i.e. `VariableName13`, `strDLink`, `strZone`. 
A single file contains about 150+ events and each project contains about 700-900 files.

In VBA environment, I want to parse through each file, loop through each event and extract the Variable names declared or referenced by the Events.

I did find some material like `Roslyn` or `TypeLib` but unable to understand how to use them?

Can someone please share a proper approach to extract the variables?

`Environment: VBA 6, SCADA HMI`

```
Private Sub Rect13_Click()
Dim lResult As Long
Dim strDLink As String
Dim strZone As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
lResult = OpenFuncUpdate
If lResult = SomeValue Then
    'DoThis
ElseIf lResult = SomeOtherValue Then
    strDLink = "FullPathLink"
    FuncDisassemblePath strDLink, , , , , , , , , , , , strZone
    If Len(strZone) > 0 And (InStr(VariableName13.CurrentValue, "%") = 0) Then
        SubLoadIA strZone & "%" & VariableName13.CurrentValue, Me
    Else
        SubLoadIA VariableName13.CurrentValue, Me
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    SubHandleError
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are using VBA or VB6?

Comment: There are many ways you could go about tackling it, but I've always had success using the [Vbscript Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264100/regex-vba-in-access-finding-text-between-two-strings)

Comment: @braX Its a VBA , built for HMI SCADA systems.

Comment: If you decide to go with regex, something like `\b(?:Dim|ReDim|Set|Public|Private|Global|Static)\s+(?!(?:Sub|Function|Property)\b)([a-z]\w*)[!@#$%^&]?(?!\S)` might be a good start (with an IgnoreCase flag, obviously). That being said, @MathieuGuindon is probably right. There could be other edge cases that this regex pattern doesn't cover. Moreover, `ReDim` and `Set` will most likely cause the returned list to contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you define what a "variable" is, you can try to parse VBA code with VBA code and regular expressions.

If **all** your declarations are *consistently* made, and *consistently* declare a single variable, and variables are *consistently* declared (`Option Explicit` is in every module), then capturing `Dim|Private|Public|Friend|Global {identifier}` should be good-enough... but that makes a lot of "ifs"

Real-life projects have `Dim` statements that can declare a *list* of local or private variables. Or there's a `ReDim` statement somewhere that's actually declaring an array on-the-spot. Or they don't always specify `Option Explicit` and variables aren't always even declared at all. Or there's a *line continuation* in the middle of the statement that breaks the regular expression. Or, or, or... so many things can go wrong, parsing VBA code is a rabbit hole.

For example suppose you need to pick up and list undeclared variables. A regular expression can't tell its usage from a procedure or function call, because they're *syntactically identical*. Regular expressions are missing the *context* of the grammar - and it's by *tokenizing* (aka "lexing") the source code and then *parsing* the tokens using *parser rules* that we can be 100% certain of what we're looking at.

Fortunately this is a solved problem, and there's free, open-source VBIDE tooling available for this, and get you 100% correct results every time *without writing a single line of code* or worrying about what legal declarations might be left unaccounted for.

[Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) (I manage this OSS project and own its website) will correctly parse any legal VB6/vBA code (and if it doesn't, we're extremely interested in a repro!), and then you can simply click a "copy" button to instantly have every single declaration in the clipboard:

[image: Rubberduck's Code Explorer "copy to clipboard" command]

Ctrl+V /paste onto a worksheet (or a Word document, or in Notepad!) and then you can easily turn it into a filter-enabled table; in your case you'd want to filter the [Declaration Type] for "Variable":

[image: Ruberduck User Declarations export]

Above, the exported declarations for a VBA project that has a `Sheet1` module with a `test` procedure that uses (but doesn't declare) a variable named `undeclared`:

```vb
Sub test()
    undeclared = 42
    Debug.Print undeclared
End Sub
```

---

Here's the same table for the code you've provided:

[image]

Note that `SubHandleError` and other `Sub` and `Function` calls would parse as and resolve to a procedure/function in your project. Here they're being picked up as undeclared variables **because I didn't parse anything other than the code you supplied**, so these identifiers are undefined.

Comment: This is an Amazing Tool you have made. And thanks for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, It will not work in my case as a lot of Legal Variables and Legal Procedure Calls are classified under the same umbrella and there seems to be no way to segregate them.

The Why: My main goal is to compare two similar events, direct comparison won't work. A little complex method was to get referenced variables from both events and compare them.

Comment: I apologize and I highly respect the tool and those made by dozens of people. The codes written in our projects are highly unstandardized, hence despite the best efforts, pre-processing the codes from our side is a mammoth task. These are pretty old projects > 10 years ago, and as you rightly said "consistently declare a single variable, and variables are consistently declared" which is not done in our case at all. The problem is not with your Software but with our source codes.

And yes it does work for the Variables which are declared, but in our case 70% are undeclared.

Comment: @PratikV trust me, Rubberduck will even find your undeclared variables in your 10-year-old code. Instead of just dismissing it out of hand, go ahead and give it a try, you might be amazed! _Rubberduck user, unofficial head tester, big fan, occasional contributor._

Comment: @PratikV It looks like you misunderstood (parts of) this answer. The part that says _"consistently declare a single variable..."_ talks about what _might_ work for _regex solutions_, not what Rubberduck can do (which includes recognizing undeclared variables).